# CSS marquee text animation not displaying properly on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm having trouble getting my marquee text to display correctly on mobile devices. It basically cuts off the text and you see only part of it moving across the screen. I think it has to do with the overflow, but if i have overflow-y or visible, then it makes the width of the web page on mobile device wider than the web page itself, and the user can scroll y. If i need to make a codepen i can, the code snippet displays correctly unless you view the code on a mobile device.

```css
@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
}

@keyframes marquee-r {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.marquee {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .marquee {
    height: 6em;
  }
}

.track {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
}

.marquee-text {
  font-size: 10em;
  color: #3395F7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #3395F7;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .marquee-text {
    font-size: 6em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="track">
    <div class="marquee-text">&nbsp;Test1 &#8226; Test2 &#8226; Test3 &#8226; Test4 &#8226; Test5 &#8226;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to run just fine. What device are you testing this on?

Comment: iPhone 7, It must be something else that i have on the page that's is messing with it. I will generate a test page and test it with just the code above and see if its still doing it on my phone.

Comment: I just tested the code after removing my SVG masked image, and the marquee is working fine on mobile devices. So now i need to debug my SVG image & jQuery that generates it.